# Azure DevOps deploy artifact packaged application to IIS

Tags: .net-core, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I thought this was striaght forward, apparently not!

I got this from my release pipeline in azure devops when I trigger the deployment ...

[image]

In IIS on the server I have this ...

[image]

... and my pipeline looks like this ...

[image]

So at this point I figure my question is obvious, what did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! Now I feel stupid, running the deployment on the agent ... not what I was intending to do, instead I need to run the deployment on the deployment group!

[image]

.. subtle stupidity on my part!

Comment: Sorry about that, stackoverflow imposes a delay on such things otherwise I would have done it as soon as I posted my solution.